# In Category theory, can two empty sets be isomorphic with each other?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, isomorphism

I am a Haskell beginner, and I want to make a function to determine if there can be an isomorphism between two lists.  I figure that if they have the same length > 0, the answer is yes.

But what about empty sets?  Can there be an isomorphism between empty sets?

Thanks.

Comment: In what category are your lists objects?

Comment: Are you sure you want an answer in the context of category theory?

Comment: Yes, please.  I read a fair amount of Lawvere and Schanuel's CONCEPTUAL MATHEMATICS, and that led me to Haskell.  Lacking a lot of the background training I frequently get lost, but my path was through category theory to the programming language.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, we usually think of *types* as objects in a category, not single values. It does not make sense to ask if a list (a value) is isomorphic to some other list, unless we define a "custom" category where lists are objects. In the latter case, the answer depends on how we define the category.

Anyway, in the category of sets, given any set `A`, there is exactly one function (morphism) `f : {} -> A` from the empty set `{}` to `A`. This the unique function with empty domain, which happens to coincide with the empty set. To help understand this, recall that a function `f : X -> Y` is a set of pairs

```
f = {(x0,y0),(x1,y1),....}
  with x0,x1,... in X, and y0,y1,... in Y
```

such that

```
for any x in X there is a unique y in Y satisfying (x,y) in f
```

When `X = {}`, we can not pick `x0,x1,... in X`, so the only option is to have `f = {}`, the "empty set of pairs". That `f` is a function because the condition reduces to

```
for any x in {} .......
```

which is a vacuous truth, since a universal quantification over the empty set is always true.

Hence, there is exactly one function `f : {} -> A` for any `A`. This is true even if `A = {}`, in which case `f : {} -> {}` is also an isomorphism. Indeed, we have `f = id` (since there is no other function!), and `f . f = f = id` (since there is no other function!), so `f` is its own inverse.

Comment: I thought it was going to be `absurd :: Void -> a`, not `id` ..?

Comment: @WillNess The special case `absurd :: Void -> Void` is actually equivalent to `id`. In the set category, these coincide since there are no elements in the domain, so they are "pointwise equal". In Haskell, we have bottom in `Void`, but even there both these functions map bottom to bottom, so they are the same. (Instead `absurd :: Void -> a` with `a` different from `Void` is not `id` because it has a different type)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the category, of course!

In the standard category SET, where objects are sets and arrows A -> B are functions which associate an element of B to each element of A, there is certainly an isomorphism between any two objects representing the empty set -- indeed, they're the same object!

One could also imagine a category in which sets were enriched with additional algebraic structure (so that there was a sensible forgetful functor from this category to SET) in which the additional algebraic structure allowed two objects to be distinguished despite the forgetful functor mapping them both to the empty set, in which case there might be no isomorphism between them.